# mapping integers to k-ary trees

Tags: graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, trees

Is there an algorithmic way to map the natural numbers to unique k-ary trees?

I am familiar with the work of Tychonievich who created a mapping from integers to binary trees. https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lat7h/blog/posts/434.html

Is there something similar for k-ary trees?

Comment: There is more than one way to count k-ary trees, meaning that the numeric values will be different (there are different equivalence relations...). Would you spell your definition explicitly in your *Question*?

Comment: It seems that you can follow the 2-ary solution from the link you have provided. I don't see any complication, the generalization seems to be straightforward.

Comment: I have tried extending it to the case of an n-ary tree and encountered a complication. At the end of the algorithm suggested by Tychonievich, he splits the integer into two separate integers, one for the right child and another for the left child. If I have an n-ary tree, it is not clear how many children there would be.

Comment: Do everything by analogy. You'll use base k notation. You'll have k children each time (some of them may be empty, corresponding to digit 0. (I better go back to that link and have another look).

Comment: Yes, given a non-negative integer, you extract k new integers (corresponding to children) by collecting the digits on the position = r mod k to form the r-th integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for "ranking $k$-ary trees" or "ranking $t$-ary trees" you will find several published papers on this.  For example:

[This](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0207039?casa_token=L7KsyEFGnGMAAAAA%3AtRJdKQBkcAnPHnV1GQaFhmsMHA1znPEnW942T513tvnhIhfLFposVAp5vi_XK2JmlbSVWBGlDKeS&)

[This](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0207034?casa_token=BRMD50DToJsAAAAA:3HA_MEs4gzr_HGo0uCkqtdIZGD4OzkskBQfPqL7TOg8RQ33coSr4yj1ye8owuRGoacD6r5kXZ938)